# <link rel the bootstrap-4 Source files?

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4, stylesheet

I've been developing a site with bootstrap 4 and linking externally to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

However, I need to load the site locally as the network connection isn't stable. So I downloaded the full stack bootstrap-4.0.0 Source file and added it to my WebServer directory thinking all I need to do is change the link to to point to bootstrap.min.css, like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href="http://localhost/webfiles/wp-content/themes/Cussons/bootstrap-4.0.0/dist/style.css?ver=4.9.4">
```

The site works, but I'm getting a `404 not found` for `style.css?ver=4.9.4`

All permissions at set to allow full access and I cleared caches and all of the links href's appear correct, but I cant seem to get my head around why the site wont pick up the color changes I've added to files like /assests/scss/_navbar.ccss

If anyone can see whats wrong, I'll be very grateful :)

Comment: `bootstrap/4.0.0-beta` and `bootstrap-4.0.0` are two very different versions of Bootstrap...

Comment: You should download the [pre-compiled distribution files](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/), not the source (unless you plan on building them with a SASS compiler)

Comment: But doesn’t the compiler require the external links? So if I tuning the site without an uplink I’m back to square 1

Comment: I don't understand. So you are going to compile from SASS?

Comment: Ok, there's a style that is held on the /assests/scss/_navbar.css file that's needed and if I cant cant get online I cant get the style. I'm assuming the file is associated with bootstrap-4.0.0/dist/style.css?ver=4.9.4", which if i can't get online, wont load. As it happens I decided, as the site will only be accessed over the LAN, it would be more stable to download the source file and hold everything locally

Answer (score 0):

Just download the precompiled files [here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/), place them in an accessible folder and then link them like :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="relative_path_to_css_parent_folder/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

same for the js at the bottom of the body :

```
<script src="relative_path_to_js_parent_folder/js/bootstrap.min.js">
```

or

```
<script src="relative_path_to_js_parent_folder/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">
```

Take a look at this : [How do I link to my css stylesheet for local file?](https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/5267834cabf82100cf004094)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="UI.css"> <!-- made up name-->
<script src="jquery.js"></script><!-- made up name-->
<script src="jquery.ui.js"></script><!-- made up name-->
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

> But what if the js files are all in the projects/js/ folder? Point
>   your page to this location:
>
> Assuming our HTML is in the blackjack folder, which is a sibling
>   folder to 'projects/js', then your script tags will look something
>   like this:

```
<script src="../js/script.js"></script>
```

> Notice the ../? This references the parent folder of the one the
>   document is in. We go up one level to where the js folder is.

Comment: Thanks, I already know how to link the files... This isn't about linking files. There's a style in _navbar.scss on line 113 that makes the hamburger button transparent. I've found the file and the style and changed it to a color so I can see it, but when I view it in the Dev-Inspector, it reverts back to transparent even though the file is clearly colored.